# Example connecting Android and Bluecove on a Mac

Tags: android, macos, bluetooth, rfcomm, bluecove

I have an Android device (HTC Incredible) and I would like to setup bluetooth communication between the android phone and a MacBook Pro.  I have got bluecove to start on the Mac and I have done coding using Sockets in Android, but I can not get a connection working.  Here is my andriod code

```
BluetoothDevice device = reciever.getDevice("00:25:00:XX:XX:XX"); //my bluetooth address
UUID generalUuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(generalUuid);
socket.connect();
writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
reader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
```

on the Mac

```
String serverUUID = "btspp://localhost:0000110100001000800000805F9B34FB;name=matt";
StreamConnectionNotifier notifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier) Connector.open(serverUUID);
StreamConnection connection = notifier.acceptAndOpen();
// prepare to send/receive data
byte buffer[] = new byte[100];
String msg = "hello there, client";
InputStream is = connection.openInputStream();
OutputStream os = connection.openOutputStream();
```

Any help or examples would be helpful.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I am having a similar issue except that I'm trying to connect to either BlueCove/Windows or PyBlueZ/Linux...neither connection is working with Android (but they work with each other fine).

Comment: @Matt No I never did succeed.

Comment: @Milhous Have you implemented Bluecove in android?If so let me guide to implement the saame.I'm facing a lot of problems here to.

Answer (score 0):

You change the line of code

> socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord (generalUuid);

by

> Method m;
>   m = device.getClass (). getMethod ("createRfcommSocket", new Class [] {int.class});
>
> tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke (device, 1);
>
> mmSocket = tmp;
>
> mmSocket.connect ();

in Android

Comment: I believe that code is the hack version of connecting, when android did not offically support bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bluecove for android.
add the bluecove library and the bluecove-android to your build path and the work should be easier.